# Pre-process parameters of a case class constructor without repeating the argument list

Tags: scala

I have this case class with a lot of parameters:

```
case class Document(id:String, title:String, ...12 more params.. , keywords: Seq[String])
```

For certain parameters, I need to do some string cleanup (trim, etc) before creating the object.

I know I could add a companion object with an apply function, but the LAST thing I want is to write the list of parameters TWICE in my code (case class constructor and companion object's apply).

Does Scala provide anything to help me on this?

Comment: Not really, as it kind of works against the notion of a case class. A normal class constructor or overriding `apply` would have to do it.

Comment: Use [Builder](http://blog.rafaelferreira.net/2008/07/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-scala.html) pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general recommendations would be:

- Your goal (data preprocessing) is the perfect use case of a companion object -- so it is maybe the most idiomatic solution despite the boilerplate.
- If the number of case class parameters is high the builder pattern definitely helps, since you do not have to remember the order of the parameters *and* your IDE can help you with calling the builder member functions. Using named arguments for the case class constructor allows you to use a random argument order as well but, to my knowledge, there is not IDE autocompletion for named arguments => makes a builder class slightly more convenient. However using a builder class raises the question of how to deal with enforcing the specification of certain arguments -- the simple solution may cause runtime errors; the [type-safe solution](http://blog.rafaelferreira.net/2008/07/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-scala.html) is a bit more verbose. In this regard a case class with default arguments is more elegant.

There is also this solution: Introduce an additional flag `preprocessed` with a default argument of `false`. Whenever you want to use an instance `val d: Document`, you call `d.preprocess()` implemented via the case class copy method (to avoid ever typing all your arguments again):

```
case class Document(id: String, title: String, keywords: Seq[String], preprocessed: Boolean = false) {
  def preprocess() = if (preprocessed) this else {
    this.copy(title = title.trim, preprocessed = true) // or whatever you want to do
  }
}
```

But: You cannot prevent a client to initialize `preprocessed` set to `true`.

Another option would be to make some of your parameters a `private val` and expose the corresponding getter for the preprocessed data:

```
case class Document(id: String, title: String, private val _keywords: Seq[String]) {
  val keywords = _keywords.map(kw => kw.trim)
}
```

But: Pattern matching and the default `toString` implementation will not give you quite what you want...

Comment: interesting approach: keeps the Document immutable, but falls short in the pollution of the constructor.

Comment: the `private val _keyword` solution is ugly, but worked really well. toString is behaving OK in my test. What's the problem you had? Also: my automatic JSON serialiser happily ignores the "_keyword", so I'm all set. Thanks!

Comment: @sscarduzio: The `toString` implementation uses the (unpreprocessed) `_keywords` member and not the preprocessed `keywords`. That is behavior is obviously ok (the case class knows nothing about the `keywords` getter), but it may create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

After changing context for half an hour, I looked at this problem with fresh eyes and came up with this:

```
case class Document(id: String, title: String, var keywords: Seq[String]) {
  keywords = keywords.map(kw => kw.trim)
}
```

I simply make the argument mutable adding `var` and cleanup data in the class body.

Ok I know,  my data is not immutable anymore and Martin Odersky will probably kill a kitten after seeing this, but hey.. I managed to do what I want adding **3 characters**. I call this a win :)

Comment: I did not expect you to give up immutability that easily :). There is still hope for making it a val -- see my updated answer...